# How to properly force https and www with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to use apache .htaccess rules to force all urls to be `https://www.`
For those that skim through this, please keep in mind that I can't use "domain.com" in the rewrite rule because of multiple reasons.
eg:

> `https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com`
>      `http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com`
>      `http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com`
>   But...

in my situation I have so many domains (due to being a wordpress multisite) that to add rules for each individual domain would be really inefficient. And since I use wordpress MS in network mode I have a few sites which are mapped to the base url and those sites in particular seem to break easy when trying to force https in ways other than mod rewrite.. then I need to make sure all domains use www but MU domain mapping doesn't force www for root sites from network mode... which is a mode that allows separation of sites into networks via wp multi network plugin. So this means I need to force this through a mod rewrite.
I've found these variations online but I'm not sure what would be the cleanest way to do this?

> `## force HTTPS and www
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$ [OR]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
>   RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|www)\. [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
>   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]`
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
>   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
>   RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]`

What's the best way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule for all 3 conditions:

```
## force HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment out all other rules when you test this in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Hi, I think you may have missed my host condition @anubhava ... I can't identify each domain individually in the rewrite rules.. they change too often and are way too many.... I'm thinking `%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` would be required to make this work?

Comment: Just noticed WP tag. What exactly do you have as home and site URL in WP settings?

Comment: Here's my wp-config:<br>`define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', false);
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define( 'BP_ENABLE_MULTIBLOG', true );` Home and Site URL is different for every site... it's "/" for network sites.

Comment: This is mostly an .htaccess question, the wordpress info is just intended as background information which I probably didn't need to share.

Comment: That made a redirect loop and shutdown my entire network... .... `## force HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]` didn't work

Comment: I am on AWS EBS with a linux AMI EC2. It's LAMP. Dunno if that info helps. I'm also behind cloudflare.

Comment: I have tested above rule on my Apache it is not causing any redirect loop. You can see in chrome dev tool what redirects are you getting.